# Why is my text being cut off in IE7 and firefox from left side?

Tags: css, xhtml

Why is my text being cut off in IE7 and Firefox from left side ? it looks OK only if i add `padding-left:1px`? why it's happening? I' can't give live link of site.

see problem in this screen-shot [alt text http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/458/3132736693.png](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/458/3132736693.png)

letter "W" being cut off from left side.

### CSS code

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, em, font, img, ins, sub, sup, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td 
{
border:0 none;
font-size:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
vertical-align:baseline;}

body {font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:62.5%;
line-height:1.2;}

ul {
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type:none;}

.home-boxesContainer ul {
font-size:0.9em;
margin:auto;
overflow:hidden;
width:90%;}

.home-boxesContainer ul li {
background:transparent url(Images/dot-grey.gif) repeat-x scroll left bottom;
float:left;
line-height:16px;
margin:10px 0 0;
overflow:hidden;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-right:10px;}

.home-boxesContainer ul li a {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:transparent url(Images/arrow-green.gif) no-repeat scroll right center;
color:#6CB025;
padding-right:20px;
text-decoration:none
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with certain fonts on windows, specifically Verdana, from my experience. I spent about three days looking for float bugs and such to solve this, three years ago. It occurs mainly with the capital 'w' character, but can also be a problem with 'v' too, and only with cleartype disabled.

The best solution is to use `text-indent:1px;` on your paragraphs, if you feel you need to implement a fix.

Comment: Thanks for reply - what is the different between padding-left:1px and text-indent:1px

Comment: Text indent will only apply to the first line of a block level element, (in this case the LI). It generally makes the text look slightly more natural if it flows onto more than one line.

For list nodes such as your example, padding should be fine, but you may also encounter the problem on long blocks of text, in which case the indent works slightly better.

Comment: If you are very worried about preserving the layouts, you could write a short jQuery solution to fix the issue ...

<code>
$('p, li, dt, dd').each(function() {
if ($(this).html().indexOf[0] === 'W') $(this).css('text-indent', '1px');
});
</code>

Comment: but in my example font is Arial not verdana.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see well on your screenshot, but I think its the font issue, try with different font.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there can be three reasons:

1. The container of your menu is pushed there to left making text that way
2. It may be font issue too (this happens sometimes due to fonts)
3. Try adding line-height to your list.